MS Team Apps Not Showing
I'd like to know how to fix this problem i cant add a certain app to my other account but to my main account it's showing.
and here is the my main account


Is your other account in another Tenant or has another Usage Location? Does it have different permissions?

Hello @grisha yes from my client.

Can you find other apps at your client's? Is the usage location the same? Are the settings the same?
